# Why $H^1(E(C), Z/nZ)$ is isomorphic to $H^1(E(C), Z)\bigotimes Z/nZ$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, tensor-products, elliptic-curves

Let $E(C)$ be an elliptic curve over complex field.

Why $H^1(E(C), Z/nZ)$ is isomorphic to $H^1(E(C), Z)\bigotimes Z/nZ$?

$H^1(E(C), Z/nZ)$＝$H^1(E(C), Z\bigotimes Z/nZ)$

From here, can we take out $\bigotimes$ from homology group?

P.S  If I could solve this, I can prove $H^1(E(C), Z/nZ)$ is isom to $T_\ell(E(C))$ as group.

Comment: I think you can apply the [universal coefficient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Universal_coefficient_theorem_for_cohomology).

Comment: It may be over killing, there should be easier way. Z/nZ is not flat, so cannot apply some elementary way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment into an answer: the Universal Coefficient Theorem for cohomology states that, given a topological space $X$ and an abelian group $G$, the sequence
\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ext}{Ext} \DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom} \newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}} \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
0 \to \Ext(H_{i-1}(X), G) \to H^i(X, G) \to \Hom(H_i(X), G) \to 0
\end{align*}
is exact for each $i \geq 0$. (Here $\Ext = \Ext_{\Z}^1$.) Since $E(\C)$ is homeomorphic to a torus, then $H_0(E(\C)) \cong \Z$ and $H_1(E(\C)) \cong \Z^2$. Note that $\Hom(\Z^2, \Z/n\Z) \cong (\Z/n\Z)^2$ and since $\Z$ is free, then $\Ext(\Z, \Z/n\Z) = 0$. Thus taking $X = E(\C)$, $G = \Z/n\Z$, and $i = 1$, we obtain the short exact sequence
$$
0 \to 0 \to H^1(E(\C), \Z/n\Z) \to (\Z/n\Z)^2 \to 0 \, ,
$$
so $H^1(E(\C), \Z/n\Z) \cong (\Z/n\Z)^2$.

Comment: H1(E(C),Z/nZ)・・・①  is generated by two cycles, and its coffieicnet is Z/nZ, so ① is isom to Z/nZ +Z/nZ. On the other hand, H1(E(C),Z) is isom to Z +Z , the titled isom is obvious. Inspire of this, could you tell me why you used universal coefficient theorem?

Comment: If possible, I would like to hear your  opinion.

Comment: The point is that E(C) is just torus, and it's homology group has no torsion, free Z module, so, there is no need to worry the homology group is gained just by  formal operation, Z→Z/nZ.

Comment: I used the universal coefficient theorem because it's tailor-made for this situation: computing a cohomology group with coefficients in a ring other than $\mathbb{Z}$. There may very well be an elementary way to compute $H^1(E(\mathbb{C}), \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, but I don't find what you've written in the comments to be a convincing argument. If you want to try to compute $H^1$ by hand you have to: 1) Take the chain complex $0 \to C_2 \to C_1 \to C_0 \to 0$ used to define homology (cellular is probably easiest); 2) Apply the functor $\operatorname{Hom}(\cdot, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ to...

Comment: obtain the dual cochain complex $0 \to C_0^* \to C_1^* \to C_2^* \to 0$; and 3) Compute the homology of this complex, i.e., find $\ker(C_1^* \to C_2^*)$ modulo $\operatorname{img}(C_0^* \to C_1^*)$. This is probably do-able, but I suspect you’re just going to end up proving that $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb{Z},  \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ as a byproduct, anyway. In any case, if you have an elementary method of computing $H^1$, feel free to post your answer below.

Comment: Could you tell me in which topology your argument working? Zariski topology? Euclid topology? In which topology, you claim H1(E(C,Z) is Z(E(C) is connected?)